# Thread.interrupted is changed after submitting a task

Tags: java

I observed a weird phenomenon where the value of `Thread.interruptted()` is changed after submitting a task, let me explain it using code.

```
package com.example;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
                , new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("ThreadTest-%d").build(),
                new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()
        );

        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println("ThreadTest interrupted: " + Thread.interrupted());
        Future<String> future;
        future = threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> {
            System.out.println("running thread");
            return "done";
        });
        System.out.println("ThreadTest interrupted: " + Thread.interrupted());
        String s = future.get();
        System.out.println("ThreadTest result: " + s);
    }
}
```

Run it, and I got the following output:

```
ThreadTest interrupted: true
ThreadTest interrupted: false
running thread
ThreadTest result: done
```

My question is, I've already interrupted the main thread, why it changed back to uninterrupted after I submitted a task? Is it a bug in JDK?

I'm using macOS, and my Java version is as follows:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html:

> When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method
>   `Thread.interrupted`, interrupt status is cleared.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted():

> The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method.

Please read documentation before asking questions.